# PTIJ: Why would I need to listen to informant of my Father?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

שמע בני מוסר אביך- Heed O Son to the informant of your father (Proverbs 1:8)

Firstly, we put a Moiser (informant) to death. Secondly its Lashon Harah to listen to negative things about your father

Why must I heed the informant??!?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

Listen, son—[I am] your father, an informant.

Comment: You’re saying my father is Darth Moiser...

Answer (score 4):

Sanhedrin 96b

> מבני בניו של המן למדו תורה בבני ברק

Some of Haman's descendants learned Torah in Benei Berak.

Why is this so?

Rb Wolbe explained that when something becomes totally evil, it becomes good, because evil can only exist when it has a *yenikah* from good, once that *yenikah* is sundered, the evil transposes to good.

The Chasam Sofer (Toras Moshe) says that same regarding the 49 *shaarei tumah* that the *benei yisrael* descended to in Mitzrayim. He says that when you pass through the 49th gate of *tumah* then you end up with *tov*.

Since the *moser* of your father is the most evil person you could imagine, he must have turned to *tov*, and so you should listen to him.

Comment: This would explain why we are only to listen to the moser's children, but not to the moser himself. "Hear the children of your father's informant."

Comment: @Derdeer But the gemara says that Haman's sons learned Torah in Benei Berak, not Haman himself?

Answer (score 2):

This is so absurd. None of you is understanding the verse at all. See Rashi, see the Metzudah, see the Ibn Ezra. See anyone. Instead, it means, "Listen, my son, to the rebuke/advice of your father." It is very wise.
I really think that you all need to find better ways to learn Torah; if this is what you're coming up with, maybe you should find yourself a teacher, [as our sages say](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).
Try to do better. I care about you.

Your Dad

Comment: Yes, I am, my son.

Answer (score 1):

Shlomo haMelech is warning us that Reshaim may be trying to inform on our father! We need to take action now, what are you waiting for?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, because every now and again we need that chastening reminder that someone is watching, and if we don't act in the correct way we're in trouble....

As the saying in [Mishlei 6:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.6.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he) goes:

> כִּ֤י נֵ֣ר מִ֭צְוָה וְת֣וֹרָה א֑וֹר **וְדֶ֥רֶךְ חַ֝יִּ֗ים תּוֹכְח֥וֹת מוסר**׃
>
> For the commandment is a lamp, The teaching is a light, And the way to life is the rebuke of an informant.